# Event doesn't start and returns error Data Truncated

Tags: mysql, events

I have one event in my database:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `movedate`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2015-01-08 00:00:05'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT 'Move tasks to current date if production is not fnished at previ'
DO update production set deliverydate = now() where deliverydate < now() and progress <> 2
```

Problem is that event is not executed even in my.ini in section mysqld
is set

> event_scheduler=on

If I run manually query:

```
update production set deliverydate = now() where deliverydate < now() and progress <> 2
```

then I get warnings like:

> Data truncated for column 'DeliveryDate' at row 3

The same thing, same code works fine on my PC where is installed mysql.

What I should check to see what causes that event is not fired?

Comment: What’s the column definition for `DeliveryDate`?

Comment: It holds DATE (yyyy-MM-dd)